# ISP - Multiple modems?

Tags: networking

I recently moved my furniture around in my apartment, causing me to relocate my cable modem to another wall that has the coax cable port. Without having to call my ISP i instantly received the same signal that I was receiving on the other wall. I ran a speed test and it's the same Mbps that I was receiving on the other wall.

So my question is, if I have hooked up another modem to the original coax port, will I be receiving the same Mbps on each modem? Or do ISP's whitelist the modem's mac address?

Comment: You really think you will get double the speed if you connect two modems to one cable connection? Think again.

Comment: They're two different ports, two different cables. Before you give smart responses, think again.

Comment: I think you will find that there is one ISP connection split into several ports inside your apartment. Anything else would be unusual. If you know otherwise you should have included that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coax is a shared medium with sufficient bandwidth for several hundred users coming down each cable.

However, to prevent people doing exactly what you describe they only permit specific MAC addresses on the network, and allocate bandwidth according to what service you pay for. Depending on the DOCSIS version, they may also use hardware signatures or certificates in addition to device MACs.

While you *can* add a second modem, you would *also* have to pay for a second broadband subscription in order for it to actually be able to connect.

Comment: Makes sense. That's what I  was thinking. Thanks for your help.